# How to sync Intellij Idea clipboard with the window's clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij idea IDE. Whenever I try to copy and paste any code from my browser to the IDE, it is not being pasted. Actually the last selection in the IDE is pasted every time. However if I paste it in any other application like notepad, it works fine.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Are you using any non-standard clipboard management software in your Windows installation?

Comment: No nothing as such :(

Comment: it really sucks to have to use Windows at work after 5 years using Ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the browser, not Intellij. Does it happen with all browsers? I used Intellij for Windows for 7 years and never had a problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by restarting intellij with the `invalidate cache\restart" menu option. Prior to restarting anything I'd had copied to the clipboard outside the IDE I couldn't paste, but afterward I could paste. I didn't investigate if just restarting would have worked. The menu option provides a nice way of closing all intellij windows at once on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

I found the same problem with IntelliJ 14.1.4 on Windows 7. I copy something external, use `Ctrl+V` in the IDE, but the last clipboard from the IDE is pasted instead.

I was able to resolve this by clearing the IDE clipboard, you can do this with `Ctrl+Shift+V` which opens the **Paste from History** dialog, here you will see all the IDE clipboard entries, you can click on each one and click `Delete`. I cleared all the entries, then copied again from the other application.

Now `Ctrl+V` in the IDE should give you the external clipboard item.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me quite often on win 7. Seems to be after idea is running for longer period of time / through suspend. Standard close and relaunch of all idea windows works. Is the same in versions 14 and 15 (no tested other).